# Подскажите как получить только значение из массива,то есть к примеру (42.2256)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const data = useSelector((state) => state.flight.flightCoords);
console.log(data)
```

результат в консоли :

```
[{…}]
0:{lat: 45.567673}
length:1
```

Как получить в переменную только 45.567673 ?

Comment: Ну так и получить `data[0].lat`. Куда вы в реакт с редаксом ломанулись, не зная основ js?

Comment: Так мне не надо,так я и сам умею

Comment: По другому никак, т.к. вы работаете с массивом. Хотя можно попробовать так в селекторе: `state.flight.flightCoords[0].lat` но если будет пустой массив, будет ошибка

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = useSelector((state) => state.flight.flightCoords.at(0)?.lat);
```

Тип `data` будет `number | undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
[{…}]
0:{lat: 45.567673}
length:1
```

`Array.from({1:'второй',0:'первый','2':'третий'}) //['первый','второй','третий']`

В общем, `var data=Array.from(useSelector((state) => state.flight.flightCoords));`

Я не понимаю откуда такая повсеместная *константа головного мозга (ц.)* ([больше рофлов тут](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#loading-command-files))

```
//временный список _Tarr содержащий каждое первое свойство{} для каждого элемента из Вашего списка[]
//try{}catch{} или же проверка типов в студию

var _Tarr=[]; //внезапно не const
for (var _Tvar1 of data) { //тоже самое
  for (var _Tvar2 in _Tvar1) { //тоже самое
    _Tarr.push(_Tvar1[_Tvar2]); //возможно, что у Вас не только 0, но и 1 и т.д., однако:
    break; //а Вы знаете про именованные циклы? сегодня без них всё равно
  }
}
console.log(_Tarr.join('\n')) //выводим списком что-то вида 45.567673
```

Comment: Наверное, надо начинать с языков без управления памятью. //про JS в интернете